# curl does not work from first attempt

Tags: linux, curl

I've just installed Fedora 19 LXDE. When I run curl for an URL first time it fails:

```
curl -v youtube.com
* Could not resolve host: youtube.com; Name or service not known
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: youtube.com; Name or service not known
```

If I rerun this command immediately it succeeds.

```
curl -v youtube.com
* About to connect() to youtube.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 80.239.229.212...
* Connected to youtube.com (80.239.229.212) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: youtube.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 20:05:20 GMT
< Server: gwiseguy/2.0
< Location: http://www.youtube.com/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< 
* Connection #0 to host youtube.com left intact
```

It seems that if the -4 option is specified everything works all right. What may be the problem?

nslookup works fine, no problem with resolution.

Update:

when I run strace against failing attempt I see the following errors:

```
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

and echo $LANG
    LANG=/en_US.UTF-8
Can it be related?

More information:
I use to have Fedora 15 with Gnome. Everything worked fine. Then I tried Fedora 19 with LXDE and XFCE. Both of them have the same issue with curl.


Resolution:
Seems the problem has something to do with IPv6.
1) Created ~/.curlrc with "--ipv4" inside. It solved some of browser's problem.
2) To fix yum added "ip_resolve=4" to /etc/yum.conf.

Comment: Are you able to ping ipv6 addresses? E.g. Google: `ping6 2001:4860:4860::8888`. You mentioned using curl with the `-4` flag works, and all that does is force ipv4.

Comment: I cannot ping6 2001:4860:4860::8888, but my ISP might not support it. Tried to add --ipv4 to ~/.curlrc (root's home), it is better now, but yum still produces
  curl#6 - "Could not resolve host:"
s

Answer (score 2):

Use `www.youtube.com` vs. `youtube.com`.

Full command:

```sh
curl -v www.youtube.com
```

An [HTTP 301](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) error means that the page has moved permanently to a new address. In this case it is indicated by the "Location" field in the server response:

> Location: http://www.youtube.com/

If you don't want to worry about this, you can specify the `--location` / `-L` flag so that it will follow HTTP redirects (301 & others) and then you can use `youtube.com`:

```
curl -v -L youtube.com
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not explain why the second attempt of absolutely the same command works.
I forgot to mention, that the real problem that because of than neither yum no browser works well.

Answer (score 0):

May be your ISP's DNS problem.

Try to ping your primary DNS to confirm its working status.

Comment: ping is always successful. And if I had problems with DNS would nslookup always work well?

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem on multiple (but not all) computers in my home LAN for couple of years, and finally resolved!

What worked for me: I have WiFi router from BT (my ISP). If provides its own (i.e. gateway) address as both nameservers via DHCP - apparently working as local DNS cache. Also, it broadcasts one search domain via DHCP too and it is hardcoded as 'home' (i.e. there's no way in router UI to reconfigure it).

Finally I realized that my systems not having this problem had search domains usage disabled, while newly installed (and not deeply tuned) systems stiil had 'search home' line in /etc/resolv.conf. All I needed was instructing all local DHCP clients to turn off search domains feature - sometime via config sometime directly via connecting script: specific method depends on your client, so I cannot give one-fits-all recipe here.

I only may guess that first attempt tried to search, say, youtube.com.home then router itself rejects it and next time local DNS client queries this same domain w/o adding search suffix for some short time until its NXDOMAIN cache expires (i.e. if next attempt was after about 15 mins, it failed again).

P.S. I looked up for solution multiple times in internet and found a lot of other people reporting same problem on BT routers but no solutions proposed. So, even if this scenario is not relevant to OP's problem, I'm still leaving my answer for all happy owners of BT routers.

**Update:**

BTW, disabling ipv6 never helped when I tried it. And yes, I did check /etc/nssswitch.conf and configured hosts resolution to obey only /etc/hosts and main DNS, no other thrills. None of these methods happened to be the root cause,